# Matriz con Java Script

Tags: javascript, matrices

Necesito ayuda con un trabajo, soy nuevo en lo que es programación y el profesor que me toco no nos enseña bien que digamos. Explico a grandes rasgos lo que es el ejercicio: De un presupuesto ingresado por teclado tengo que repartir entre 37 municipios, a su vez cada uno tiene que repartir a dos áreas mas. Y así para cada municipio. El problema es que tengo que usar una matriz y no se como aplicarlo. Aclaro que cada municipio tiene un porcentaje distinto.

Comment: hola @brianalex te aconsejo que estudies un poco, cosas como esas las encuentras facilmente con investigacion.

Comment: Estuve buscando y no logro entender. Por eso recurrí a este medio, otros codigos si me salieron y este no  hay caso. Me podrias ayudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realice el ejemplo que está diciendo, aunque si es una tarea, lo debería hacer ud mismo.
Lo único que hace falta es hacer la correcta distribución de los porcentajes iniciales, lo demás funciona bien.

**Html**

```
<h1>Porcentaje
  <input id="numero"/>
  <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="calcularPorcentaje()"/>
</h1>
<div id="salida"></div>
```

**javascript**

```
  var cantidadMunicipios=37;
  var municipios=[];
  for (var i=0;i<cantidadMunicipios;i++){
    // Creando número aleatorios.
    // este valor debe ajustarse todos los municipios para que el total de los 37 sea 100%, porque de otro modo se pasaría del presupuesto.
    var porcentaje=Math.round(Math.random()*30)+1;  
    var barrios=[Math.round(Math.random()*49)+1,Math.round(Math.random()*49)+1];
    //incrusta un array dentro de otro, así crea un array bidimensional
    // lo mismo sucede con la variable Barrios, ese sería el tercer nivel del array
    municipios.push(["Municipio "+(i+1),porcentaje,barrios]);
  }

var calcularPorcentaje=function(){
  var num=document.getElementById('numero').value;
  document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML = "";
  for (var i=0;i<cantidadMunicipios;i++){
    var tempElement = document.createElement('div');
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");         
        var p1 = document.createElement('p');
        var valorMunicipio=(num*municipios[i][1])/100;
        p1.innerHTML = "<b>"+municipios[i][0]+":</b> %"+municipios[i][1]+" => "+valorMunicipio;
        document.getElementById('salida').appendChild(p1);  
        for (var j=0;j<municipios[i][2].length;j++){                
            var p = document.createElement('div');                          
            p.innerHTML = "<div style='margin-left:25px'> Barrio"+(j+1)+": %"+municipios[i][2][j]+" => "+(valorMunicipio*municipios[i][2][j])/100+"</div>"
            document.getElementById('salida').appendChild(p);   
        }           
    }   
}
```

[ejemplo funcional](https://codepen.io/cvalencia/pen/vWNzrQ)